# Why should I use assert_equal instead of just assert with an equal operator in minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

I really enjoy Minitest and it's simplicity but I don't understand why I should use `assert_equal` instead of `assert` with the `==` operator.

If I look into the [Implementation](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L161) the `assert_equal` method does exactly the same as I said with the equal operator.

Why do I need this step in between and not just use it directly?

I also think that it won't be more readable just because of the `equal` there since `==` is pretty self explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you want `assert_equal` when you prefer clear failure messages.

When you write `assert a == b` and the test fails for any reason, the message would just say something along the lines of `Assertion failed`.
On the other hand, if you use `assert_equal a, b` a failure will show a message like `Expected a to be equal to b` which gives you a bit more detail about why the test failed.

Comment: This is probably the reason. It removes overhead of writing a custom message but still describes why the assertion failed. I haven't looked onto this from this perspective. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a matter of choice and for me `assert_equal` looks more readable than using `==`

```
assert_equal expect, actual
```

Comment: I think this is exactly not the case since it's much more self describing if you look onto `a == b` than onto `assert_equal a, b`. Even more if you haven't used Minitest before. But I think @eugen is right with his assumption that's because of the custom message.

Comment: @Tobias As I said it is just matter of choice and of course `assert_equal` raises a different msg if assertion fails that is another advantage.